# Flash of unstyled content with react and scss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

After migrating my CSS files to SCSS, I can see FOUC for my layout elements at the first load (After each reloads of page).

I guess it has something to do with my webpack config so I tried to fix the problem by using [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin), but I can still see the problem.

Here is the content of my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');
const MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';


module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,{
            loader: "css-loader"
          }, {
            loader: "sass-loader",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /(\.(?:le|c)ss)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: false,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'less-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: false,
              javascriptEnabled: true,
            },
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new MomentLocalesPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@ant-design/icons/lib/dist$": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/icons.js")
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Could you see in the chrome profiler when your CSS is coming? If the CSS is pretty long then FOUC will be there. Try to optimize CSS and identify the Critical CSS. This might not be the issue of webpack.

Comment: It's very unlikely that converting CSS to SCSS can cause such a problem if all you did is add scss-loader. Can you check if mini-css-extract-plugin is generating separate css files and also verify the same in the generated HTML file?

Comment: @NehaSharma Thanks, you are right. It was a stupid mistake from my side

Comment: @vatz88 Thanks, you are right. It was a stupid mistake from my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem wasn't because of Webpack. It was because of me being stupid :)

I imported the CSS file inside of a child component, so when I reload the page, it first shows the layout without any styles and then loads the child component and gives the layout a proper style. So basically, the only thing I did to fix the problem was to import the style in the layout component.

```
import '../style.scsc'
```